# How to tell jest to make a snapshot per file?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, snapshot, babel-jest

Is there any way to tell jest to store a snapshot per file ?

Let's say, in some test suite I have many snapshots and I don't want them to be stored in a single file. The file will become huge and the experience with a file being huge in debugging and code review becomes terrible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [jest-specific-snapshot](https://github.com/igor-dv/jest-specific-snapshot)

Comment: I ended up using it and stubing it even further. thanks a lot for the suggestion